# How to configure Adobe LiveCycle Data service 4.7 with Adobe Flash Builder 4.6?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, flexbuilder

I am using **Adobe Live Cycle Data Service (LCDS) 4.7** and **Adobe Flash Builder 4.6** for developing free yahoo stock market data application, for reference pdf [click here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/livecycle/pdfs/live_stock_quote_app.pdf).

I follow the tutorial & completed Server side application using Eclipse IDE & i deployed into LCDS, now i am developing client side application by using Adobe Flash Builder 4.6. When i try to configure the **Flex project** i am getting an error, like `Only LiveCycle Data Services 2.6 and higher are supported.`  Even though i am using higher version, but i did't get why i got this error. Any suggestion are appreciated.
The error i got, Is shown in image.
[image]

Comment: Anybody give the solution for this problem??

Comment: Check to see that server side application id deployed properly and it's url is accessible from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience it requires at least following jar files under your **"Java Workspace\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib"** folder -

1. flex-messaging-core.jar
2. flex-messaging-data.jar

for your case location is- "StockDashBoard\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib" folder

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Is anybody resolved the same? I installed  LiveCycle Data Services for Java EE 4.6.1 on my C:\